# Convert System::DateTime to _timeb

Tags: c#, c++, datetime, .net-3.5

I have a legacy C++-based application that timestamps incoming network traffic using the CRT `_ftime()` function.  The `_ftime()` function returns a `_timeb` structure, which has a 32-bit and a 64-bit implementation.  We are using the 32-bit implementation, which looks like this:

```
struct _timeb {
    long time;              // 4 bytes
    unsigned short millitm; // 2 bytes
    short timezone;         // 2 bytes
    short dstflag;          // 2 bytes
};
```

From the MSDN documentation, here is how each field is interpreted:

- **dstflag** - nonzero if daylight savings time is currently in effect for the local time zone (see `_tzset` for an explanation of how daylight savings time is determined.)
- **millitm** - fraction of a second in milliseconds
- **time** - time in seconds since midnight (00:00:00), January 1, 1970, coordinated universal time (UTC).
- **timezone** - difference in minutes, moving westward, between UTC and local time.  The value of timezone is set from the value of the global variable `_timezone` (see `_tzset`).

I am re-working the portion of the code that does the timestamping to use C# in **.NET 3.5**.  Timestamps are now generated using the `System.DateTime` structure, but I still need to convert them back to the `_timeb` structure so the legacy C++ code can operate on them.  Here is how I am doing that in my managed C++ bridge library:

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime::UtcNow;
DateTime baseTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind::Utc);
TimeSpan delta = dateTime - baseTime;

_timeb timestamp;
timestamp.time     = delta.TotalSeconds;
timestamp.millitm  = dateTime.Millisecond;
timestamp.dstflag  = TimeZoneInfo::Local->IsDaylightSavingTime(dateTime) ? 1 : 0;
timestamp.timezone = TimeZoneInfo::Local->BaseUtcOffset.TotalMinutes * -1;
```

From what I can tell, this appears to reconstruct the `_timeb` structure as if I had called `_ftime()` directly, and that's good.  The thing is, timestamps are a critical piece of our application, so this has to be right.

My question is two-fold.

1. Is my algorithm flawed somehow?  Does anyone see anything obvious that I've missed?  Are there boundary conditions where this won't work right?
2. Is there a better way to do the conversion?  Does .NET have a way to do this in a more straightforward manner?

Comment: how is that answer solve your problem? hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're aware of the Y2K38 problem?  I assume you checked the sign of .timezone.  Avoid the cleverness of using dateTime.Millisecond, that just confuses the next guy.  Looks good otherwise.

Comment: Not so worried about Y2K38. :)  What do you mean regarding the cleverness of dateTime.Millisecond?